# Sort algorithm in dirent.h

Tags: c++, sorting

im playing with dirent library and i cant sort my directory list.

I have this comparator function:

```
bool comparator (const dirent &a, const dirent &b) {
        return a.d_name<b.d_name;

}
```

and main:

```
int main (){
    vector<dirent> dirs;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *drnt = NULL;
    dir = opendir("./");

    if(dir)
        {
                while(drnt = readdir(dir))
                {
                        dirs.push_back(*drnt);
                        //printf("%-20s\n", drnt->d_name);
                }
                closedir(dir);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Can not open directory\n");
        }

        sort(dirs.begin(), dirs.end(), comparator);

        cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.size(); i++){
                cout << dirs[i].d_name << endl;
        }    
    return 0;
}
```

But the sort is wrong... can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Too localized. Not like this hasn't been asked thousadns of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `d_name` field of a `dirent` structure is a C-style string, not a C++ `std::string`.  You can't compare them with `<`.  Use [`strcmp(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcmp/):

```
bool comparator (const dirent &a, const dirent &b)
{
    if (strcmp(a.d_name, b.d_name) < 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Or rather, you *can* compare them with `<`, but it doesn't mean what you want it to...

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a pointer comparison on the `d_name` fields of your `dirents`.  This is almost certainly not what you want, since the elements of a vector are already sorted by pointer order.  You want to use `strcmp` instead.